# Is there any difference in meaning between these two statements

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading text that states

> the vector $\ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n} $ is $\ s$-sparse if at most $\ s<n$ of its entries are non-zero

Is that any different from stating:

> the vector $\ x$ is $\ s$-sparse if $\ s<n$ of its entries are non-zero.

I don't see the difference and I find the first redundant; if I'm stating that $\ x$ is $\ s$-sparse then could $\ x$ have anything other than $\ s$ non-zero entries?

**Definition** of an $\ s$-sparse:
A vector $\ x \in \mathbb{R}^{N} $ is called $\ s$-sparse if at most $\ s $ of its entries are nonzero, i.e. if

$\ \|x\|_{\ell_0} := card(supp(x))\le s $

where $\ supp(x) := \{j \in [N] : x_j \ne 0\} $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statements are not equivalent. The second proposed definition would imply that the zero vector $(0, 0, ..., 0)$ isn't $s$-sparse unless $s = 0$, since the zero vector has exactly $0$ non-zero entries.

However, the zero vector is $s$-sparse according to the first definition.

Comment: is the zero vector a sparse vector?! why?

Comment: @val According to the first definition, yes (provided $s > 0$): It has $0$ non-zero entries, and $0 < s$.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I got it now.

Answer (score 2):

The vector $(1, 0, \text{<500 more zeros>})$ is 12-sparse according to the first definition, but not according to the second.

Comment: One reason to care about sparse vectors is that things like computing dot products can be much faster for them. If you have a pair of $n$-vectors, computing the dot product takes $O(n)$ time; if they're both $\ln n$-sparse, then it takes only $O(\ln n)$. 
But suppose I know that I'll be looking at vectors in the $(x,y,z,0,0,...,0)$ subspace of $R^{200}$. What I can say with confidence is that those vectors are all $3$-sparse. But some of them, like $(0, 1, 0, 0, ..., 0)$ might not actually have three nonzero entries. It'd be annoying to have to make special-case claims for these.